# Retrofit deserializer for every response

Tags: java, android, jackson

I have to call a webservices which return a response like this one below for every object I query (user, customer, provider....)

```
{"result":
   {"code":"OK",
    "message": {"id":"1",
                "name":"YingYang",
                "mail":"somemail@gmail.com",
                "password":"EDB5FG12BG117KMNJSYHH",
                "validated":"1",
                "status":"Just fine",
                "ranking":"99"}
   }
}
```

The thing is that I need to get the object "user" (or customer or whatever) when 'code' is OK, and a string message/error when 'code' is KO.

I know this structure is quite common for webservices, but I just cant find the way to handle them.

I guess I have to create a custom deserializer to do the job, and this is what I've got so far:

```
class UserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User>
{
    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        User user = new User();
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        ApiResult result = new ApiResult();

        result.code = (String) node.get("result").get("code").toString();
        result.message = (String) node.get("result").get("message").toString();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode messageObj = mapper.readTree(result.message);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = messageObj.fields();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            Field field = null;
            try {
                field = User.class.getField((String) e.getKey());
                if(field.getType().getName().equals("java.lang.String")) {
                    field.set(user, e.getValue().toString().replace("\"",""));
                }
                if(field.getType().getName().equals("int")) {
                    field.set(user, Integer.parseInt(e.getValue().toString().replace("\"","")));
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me out to make this generic for all Api responses for all objects and to generate some kind of message/error when the "code" is "KO"?

Comment: the stuff in message is generic right? `{"result":
   {"code":"OK",
    "message":<generic object>
}` ; and BTW, your JSON is invalid, you cannot nest objects like that

Comment: JSON corrected. I guess I was trying to explain that "message" is a "user" now, but might be a "customer" or anything else when "code" is "OK" and a string "error:......" when "code" is "KO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you need is something like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "code")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Result.Error.class, name = "KO"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = User.class, name = "<your string to determine whether the message is a user or not>") })
static class Result {
    String code;

    Message message;

    interface Message {
        int id();
        // other common properties...
    }

    static class Error implements Message {

        @Override
        public int id() {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    static class User implements Message {

        public int id;
        public String name;

        // other fields...

        @Override
        public int id() {
            return id;
        }
    }

}
```

You don't need to use an interface for `Message`, an abstract class would work as well. The idea is that all of your messages(including error) all implements/extends a common type. The annotations tell Jackson how to deserialize the JSON based on the `code` property.

Now, in order for this to work, you will have to tell Jackson about the message's type. You can either do it through the `code` parameter like the code above and have your JSON look something like this:

```
{"result":
   {"code":"USER",
    "message": {"<your user>"}
   }
}
// another example
{"result":
   {"code":"PROVIDER",
    "message": {"<your provider>"}
   }
}
```

Or you can simply specify the type(class) when you deserialize the JSON.

And as always, try to make your fields final/immutable. One simple way of doing that with Jackson is through constructors, annotate your parameters in the constructor and mark it with `@JsonCreator`. If you are using Java 8 then [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-parameter-names) would be extremely useful.